How to create strapi api token (from env variable) on startup for usage in my backend container?
I wanted to know how I can create an strapi api token, so that I can start my terraform/docker setup with an STRAPI_API_TOKEN env variable already being injected. I want to do that without needing to manually create an STRAPI_API_TOKEN using the admin interfact. I want to create that token and inject it into my backend container as an ENV Variable, which means the creation should be somehow performed when starting strapi, then the created token needs to be exported and injected into the upcoming backend container.
Do you have any ideas on how to realise that? I would love to let the hole setup be working by using terraform. But in first place it would be great to understand how to provision the API_TOKEN and then
A thing that i thought about was to start the setup one time, create an API token and then inject the previously created and hashed API_TOKEN into the strapi_api_tokens table inside my postgresql db.
